# Is there a Spanish equivalent for "OP"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, traducción

The English abbreviation *OP* for the term *Original Poster* is widely used over the internet. Do the abbreviation and/or the term have widely used equivalents in Spanish?

Comment: Interesting question. I doubt it though....

Comment: There must be plenty of "forum" software localized into or at least used by Spanish speakers though...

Comment: Two issues here: internet usage is more recent in Spanish speaking territories and less intense. Also, keep in mind that Spanish is a language a lot less "acronym-friendly" than English. They are not forbidden, but they take a lot more time to get accepted (v.g., there are no acronyms equivalents to CEO, CTO, etc).

Comment: If you search for "posteador original" in Google, there are 15.400 results. But "posteador" is not an official Spanish word, but there are some people who use it. I've never seen any other acronym but the English one "OP".

Comment: I didn't realize "OP" was even widely used, except on SE sites.

Comment: @SJuan76 "internet usage is more recent in Spanish speaking territories"? Don't agree at all. There have been forums in Spanish since 10+ years ago, and even 10 sounds conservative. Also, I see no reason to translate acronyms. They should stay in the language they were first coined.

Comment: @silverCORE The fact that they exist a long time ago doesn't mean they can be compared in intensity of usage to English ones.

Comment: @Flimzy: It's definitely common, I've seen it on several other forums.

Comment: @jrdioko: I just saw (or at least noticed) it for the first time today on http://forums.tdiclub.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there really is an accurate translation.

Of course you could literally translate Original Poster in various different ways, the point of *OP* is to make a very short abbreviation that is **very easily recognizable**.

So, given that there is no universal set for Spanish, any literal translation you choose will be ok but you won't be able to shorten it.

If it was me, if the site has a relatively internet active community, I would use *OP*, and explain if it is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

*Creador del hilo* is a correct, quickly understandable (as in *no-brainer* - which is good!) and widely used translation of *original poster*.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use OP and be done with it. Thanks to [the Academies in charge](http://www.asale.org/ASALE/Index) [of its standardization](http://www.rae.es), the official Spanish language often evolves more slowly than the needs of its speakers, so quite often you will end up having to choose between deviating from standard Spanish and not being able to say what you want to say.